# dashboard for interfaces monitoring

Tags: web-services, web, interface

We are working on a huge project with a lot of different type on interfaces. The xml data from these interfaces are being loaded in a loading zone ( server) at different times ( weekly, daily etc). We are looking to create a dashboard to display and monitor the interfaces. Is anyone aware of any tools/software, open source or otherwise, that can be configured/build for this purpose? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to recommend a tool but I will tell you what to look for. Essentially this type of activity is called Business Activity Monitoring(BAM). You will need to look at a BAM tool if you want to achieve this. So go google for a BAM tool.

Keep in mind this might require some code changes on your interfaces as they will have to alert the BAM monitor about what is happening when.